# Wa-Tor simulation

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I tried [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingPrompts/comments/26i7is/wator_population_dynamics_simulation/) as a programming exercise. It's working as intended, but I feel like the code is a mess and I could have used the advantages of object oriented programming much more (like inheritance for fish and shark from the `Cell` class, and probably much more). Can someone guide me a bit through this code example and show me how to make this more object-oriented?

The code simulates an ocean populated by fish and sharks:

- Sharks hunt fish
- Fish swim and breed
- Sharks die of starvation after x years

The ocean, fish and sharks are all represented by a `Cell` class. The objects are stored in a 2D array and then painted onto the Windows form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;


namespace WaTor
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    //Gritsize width(x) and height(y)
    const int TableX = 10;
    const int TableY = 10;
    const int pixelSizeX = 19;
    const int pixelSizeY = 19;

    //Fish Properties
    int initialNumberOfFish = 2;
    int initialNumberOfSharks = 2;
    int ageToBreedFish = 5;
    int ageToBreedShark = 10;
    int yearToStarvation = 5;

    int sharkScent = 3;

    Random rnd = new Random();

    Cell[,] myArray = new Cell[TableX, TableY];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        intitializeArray();
    }

    private void intitializeArray()
    {

        int x = 0; //Position on X-Axis
        int y = 0; //Position on Y-Axis
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {      
                Cell newCellX = new Cell();
                myArray[i,j] = newCellX;
                myArray[i,j].posX = x;
                myArray[i,j].posY = y;
                x = x + pixelSizeX+1;


            }
            x = 0;
            y = y + pixelSizeY+1;

        }

    }

    //Only used to paint the results
    private void Canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Graphics g = Canvas.CreateGraphics();
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Brush b = new SolidBrush(myArray[i,j].cellColor);
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(myArray[i,j].posX, myArray[i,j].posY, pixelSizeX, pixelSizeY);
                g.FillRectangle(b, r);

            }
        }

    }
    //Only used when initializing a new simulation
    public void populate()
    {

        //Clean the grid
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                kill(i, j);
            }
        }
        //Distribute Fish randomly
        int PosX=0;
        int PosY=0;
        bool isEmpty=false;

        Random rndX = new Random();
        Random rndY = new Random();
        PosX = rndX.Next(0, TableX);

        for (int i = 0; i < initialNumberOfFish; i++)
        {
            while (!isEmpty)
            {
                PosX = rndX.Next(TableX);
                PosY = rndY.Next(TableY);

                if (myArray[PosX, PosY].fishType == fishTypeEnum.empty)
                    isEmpty = true;

            }

            myArray[PosX, PosY].fishType = fishTypeEnum.fish;
            myArray[PosX, PosY].cellColor = Color.Green;
            myArray[PosX, PosY].age = rndX.Next(0, ageToBreedFish);
            isEmpty = false;

        }

        //Distribute Sharks randomly
        for (int i = 0; i < initialNumberOfSharks; i++)
        {
            while (!isEmpty)
            {
                PosX = rndX.Next(0, TableX);
                PosY = rndY.Next(0, TableY);

                if (myArray[PosX, PosY].fishType != fishTypeEnum.shark)
                    isEmpty = true;
            }
            myArray[PosX, PosY].fishType = fishTypeEnum.shark;
            myArray[PosX, PosY].cellColor = Color.Red;
            myArray[PosX, PosY].age = rndX.Next(0, yearToStarvation);
            myArray[PosX, PosY].ageStarvation = myArray[PosX, PosY].age;
            isEmpty = false;

        }

    }

    //A tick is a 'round' where fish swim and breed, sharks hunt and breed
    public void tick()
    {
        bool reproduce;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {

                //If Cell is Shark and hasent moved
                if ((myArray[i, j].fishType == fishTypeEnum.shark) && (!myArray[i, j].moved))
                {                        

                    //Sharks starve
                    Debug.WriteLine("Hai alter"+myArray[i,j].age);
                    if (myArray[i, j].ageStarvation > yearToStarvation)
                    {
                        kill(i, j);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Hai verhungert");
                    }

                    //If not starved shark hunts
                    hunt(i, j);    

                }

                else
                    //If Cell is Fish and hasent moved
                    if ((myArray[i, j].fishType == fishTypeEnum.fish) && (!myArray[i, j].moved))
                    {
                        reproduce = false;
                        if (myArray[i,j].age >= ageToBreedFish)
                        {
                            reproduce = true;
                        }
                        move(i, j, fishTypeEnum.fish, reproduce);
                    }

                }
            }

        //End Tick
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                myArray[i, j].moved = false;
            }
        }

    }

    private void kill(int x, int y)
    {
        myArray[x, y].age = 0;
        myArray[x, y].fishType = fishTypeEnum.empty;
        myArray[x, y].cellColor = Color.Blue;
        myArray[x, y].moved = false;
    }

    private void hunt(int x, int y)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int direction = 0;
        int newX = x;
        int newY = y;
        bool moved = false;

        //Check for Fish nearby
        direction = fishNearBy(x, y, sharkScent);
        Debug.WriteLine("direction: " + direction);

        if (direction == 0)
            direction = rnd.Next(1, 5);                
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case 1://East. If Index 0 move to TableEnde
                    if (newY > 0)
                    {
                        newY = newY - 1;
                        moved = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newY = TableY - 1;
                        moved = true;
                    }

                    break;
                case 2://West. If TableEnde move to 0.
                    if (newY < TableY - 1)
                    {
                        newY = newY + 1;
                        moved = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newY = 0;
                        moved = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3://North. If top reached try again
                    if (newX > 0)
                    {
                        newX = newX - 1;
                        moved = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 4://South. If bottom reached try again
                    if (newX < TableX - 1)
                    {
                        newX = newX + 1;
                        moved = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }//switch
        }//if
        if (myArray[newX, newY].fishType == fishTypeEnum.fish)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Fisch gefangen");
            eatFish(newX, newY);
            myArray[x, y].ageStarvation = 0; ;
        }

        if (moved)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hai bewegen");
            myArray[newX, newY].cellColor = myArray[x, y].cellColor;
            myArray[newX, newY].fishType = myArray[x, y].fishType;
            myArray[newX, newY].age = myArray[x, y].age + 1;
            myArray[newX, newY].ageStarvation = myArray[x, y].ageStarvation + 1;
            myArray[newX, newY].moved = true;


            //Shark will breed
            if (myArray[newX, newY].age >= ageToBreedShark)
            {
                myArray[newX, newY].age = 0;
                myArray[newX, newY].ageStarvation = 0;
                myArray[x, y].age = 0;
                myArray[x, y].ageStarvation = 0;
                myArray[x, y].moved = true;
            }
            else
            {
                kill(x, y); 
            }

        }
    }

    private void eatFish(int x, int y)
    {
        kill(x, y);
    }

    private void resetXY(ref int x, ref int y, int a,int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

    //Searches for fish. howFar determines how many cells away sharks can find fish
    private int fishNearBy(int x, int y, int howFar)
    {
        int checkX = x;
        int checkY = y;
        int howClose =howFar+2;
        bool fishFound = false;
        int direction=0; //1=East, 2=West, 3=North, 4=South

        //Array for saving the direction. Distance initialized with howfar(maxlength)
        int[] directionArray = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < directionArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            directionArray[i] = howFar + 1;


        //Check East
        for (int i = 0; i < howFar; i++)
        {
            if (checkY < 0)
            {
                checkY = TableY - 1;
            }

            if (myArray[x, checkY].fishType == fishTypeEnum.fish)
            {
                //Update distance
                directionArray[1] = i;
                fishFound = true;
                break;
            }
            checkY--;
            directionArray[1] = 99;
        }

        resetXY(ref checkX, ref checkY, x, y);

        //Check West
        for (int i = 0; i < howFar; i++)
        {
            if (checkY >= TableY)
            {
                checkY = 0;
            }

            if (myArray[x, checkY].fishType == fishTypeEnum.fish)
            {
                //Update distance
                directionArray[2] = i;
                fishFound = true;
                break;
            }
            checkY++;
            directionArray[2] = 99;
        }


        resetXY(ref checkX, ref checkY, x, y);
        //Check North
        for (int i = 0; i < howFar; i++)
        {
            if (checkX <= 0)
            {
                checkX = 0;
            }

            if (myArray[checkX, y].fishType == fishTypeEnum.fish)
            {
                //Update distance
                directionArray[3] = i;
                fishFound = true;
                break;
            }
            checkX--;
            directionArray[3] = 99;

        }

        resetXY(ref checkX, ref checkY, x, y);

        //Check South
        for (int i = 0; i < howFar; i++)
        {
            if (checkX >= TableX)
            {
                checkX = TableX-1;
            }

            if (myArray[checkX, y].fishType == fishTypeEnum.fish)
            {
                //Update distance
                directionArray[4] = i;
                fishFound = true;
                break;
            }
            checkX++;
            directionArray[4] = 99;

        }
        if (fishFound)
        {
            //Find the fish that is closest to the shark
            for (int i = 1; i < directionArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Fish found, Index: " + Array.IndexOf(directionArray, directionArray[i]) + " Entfernung: " + directionArray[i]);
                if (directionArray[i] < howClose)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Fish found, direction: " + Array.IndexOf(directionArray, directionArray[i]));
                    howClose = directionArray[i];

                }
                direction = Array.IndexOf(directionArray, howClose);
            }

        }
        return direction;

    }

    private void move(int x, int y,fishTypeEnum type,bool repro)
    {

        int newX=x;
        int newY=y;
        int direction = 4;
        bool cellIsFree = false;
        bool noFreeCells = false;
        int numberOfTries = 0;
        int maxTries = 8;

        if ((type == fishTypeEnum.fish))
        {
            while (!cellIsFree && !noFreeCells)
            {
                direction = rnd.Next(1, 5);//Direction between 1-4 
                switch (direction)
                {
                    case 1://East. If Index 0 move to TableEnde
                        if (newY > 0)
                        {
                            newY = newY - 1;
                        }

                        else

                            newY = TableY - 1;
                        break;

                    case 2://West. If TableEnde move to 0.
                        if (newY < TableY - 1)
                        {
                            newY = newY + 1;
                        }

                        else

                            newY = 0;
                        break;

                    case 3://North. If top reached try again
                        if (newX > 0)
                        {
                            newX = newX - 1;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 4://South. If bottom reached try again
                        if (newX < TableX - 1)
                        {
                            newX = newX + 1;
                        }
                        break;
                }//switch
                if (myArray[newX, newY].fishType == fishTypeEnum.empty)
                {
                    cellIsFree = true;

                }
                numberOfTries++;

                if (numberOfTries > maxTries)
                    noFreeCells = true;

            }//if



        }//while (!cellIsFree)


        //Debug.WriteLine("NewX=" + newX + "NewY=" + newY);
        myArray[newX, newY].cellColor = myArray[x, y].cellColor;
        myArray[newX, newY].fishType = myArray[x, y].fishType;
        myArray[newX, newY].moved = true;
        myArray[newX, newY].age = myArray[x, y].age + 1;


        //If fish ist not reproducing remove the previous fish
        if (!repro)
        {
            kill(x, y);
        }
        else
        {
            myArray[newX, newY].age = 0;
            myArray[x, y].age = 0;
            myArray[x, y].moved = true;
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tick();
        Canvas.Refresh();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populate();
        Canvas.Refresh();

    }

}
}
```

The `Cell` class is used to store information about the cells:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WaTor

{
//Fishtype
enum fishTypeEnum { fish, shark, empty };

class Cell
{

    //Color
    public Color cellColor { get; set; }

    //Age
    public int age {get;set;}

    //Age used for starvation
    public int ageStarvation { get; set; } 

    //Set&Get Fishtype
    public fishTypeEnum fishType {get;set;}

    //Check if moved during tick
    public bool moved { get; set; }

    //Position
    public int posX {get;set;}
    public int posY {get;set;}

    //Constructor
    public Cell()
    {
        cellColor = Color.Blue;
        posX = 0;
        posY = 0;
        age = 0;
        ageStarvation = 0;
        moved = false;
        fishType = fishTypeEnum.empty;
    }



}


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! [the wator simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa-Tor) ist what my code does, i mention that in the title.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit tired now but i'll give a full go at this later. In the short term the most obvious problem  is highlighted by your comments. look at the populate function. why tell me what its doing. you know what would be better? Populate()
{
 CleanTheGrid();
 DistributeFish();
 DistributeSharks();
} . read up on SRP (Single Responsibility Principle). same goes for the tick function. quick example: tick()
{
 var currentCell = myArray[i,j];
 if(IsShark(currentCell))
   updateShark();
 else
     updateFish();
}. try simple refactor into single units of work. then further OOP designs will appear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all I would suggest you [separate your concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) a little more.  At the moment you have (most of) your [Wa-Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa-Tor) logic *AND* your Windows Forms code all together in the **same** class.  Secondly, *that* class is named **Form1**!  I know Visual Studio is nice when it does things for you, but naming classes isn't it's strong-suit ;)

### Separate your presentation from your (domain) logic

As you get into more complex problem spaces, things like [decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_%28computer_science%29) and [domain modelling](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) become important steps in translating the problem space into *abstractions* that you can compose together.
Imagine if your Wa-Tor simulation was actually being run on a super computer, in order to produce an accurate model of sea-life populations and breeding patterns in the Pacific Ocean. This would obviously be a massive increase in scope, but *shouldn't* require any particularly large code changes* (known as refactoring) **if your code has been written in a re-usable, decomposed, loosely-coupled way** (which is the goal of all OOP coders).

<sup>* well, assuming the logic of Wa-Tor is *exactly* how the Ocean works.</sup>

I would suggest that things such as `initialNumberOfFish`,
`initialNumberOfSharks`, `ageToBreedFish`, `ageToBreedShark` & `yearToStarvation`, etc **all** belong somewhere other than the (presentation) class `Form1`.  The same goes for the storage, size and initialization (`intitializeArray`) of your array (a better name for which might be "*world*", or ocean, etc).  That class should probably be something along the lines of `Simulation`, `World`, etc.

The code in `intitializeArray` can go into the **constructor** of that `Simulation` class.  That constructor can also accept all of the configuration parameters of the simulation (size, age to breed number of fish, etc) as arguments.  It can also then call the `populate` method.

Also, an additional problem of your presentation code infecting your logical (model) code.. Why does a `Cell` have a `cellColor`?  *Colors* are something pertaining to *display*, the `Cell` may have a *state, status, type* or even an `isEmpty` property - as these all relate to the *simulation* (which is what the Cell is part of modelling).

---

### Abstract your behaviours as well as your representations...

### - OR :  "Don't repeat yourself!"

As [@apieceoffruit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/33885/apieceoffruit) commented, the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (closely related to the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) I mentioned earlier) should be employed when you are deciding upon the responsibilities for your objects (often called ["Don't Repeat Yourself", or DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)).  Since objects contain both data (*i.e.* fields) and behaviour (methods), this principle should be used (as [@apieceoffruit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/33885/apieceoffruit) said) when designing your methods.

In particular, the `populate` method, contains the following code:

> ```
>    //Distribute Fish randomly
>     int PosX=0;
>     int PosY=0;
>     bool isEmpty=false;
>     Random rndX = new Random();
>     Random rndY = new Random();
>     PosX = rndX.Next(0, TableX);
>     for (int i = 0; i < initialNumberOfFish; i++)
>     {
>         while (!isEmpty)
>         {
>             PosX = rndX.Next(TableX);
>             PosY = rndY.Next(TableY);
>             if (myArray[PosX, PosY].fishType == fishTypeEnum.empty)
>                 isEmpty = true;
>         }
>         myArray[PosX, PosY].fishType = fishTypeEnum.fish;
>         myArray[PosX, PosY].cellColor = Color.Green;
>         myArray[PosX, PosY].age = rndX.Next(0, ageToBreedFish);
>         isEmpty = false;
>     }
> ```

Which is then *almost* **copied verbatim** for "Distribute Sharks randomly" (obviously with `fishTypeEnum.shark` used instead, etc).

This could (and would) be much better *Decomposed* into a helper method `DistributeRandomly`, or (as [@apieceoffruit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/33885/apieceoffruit) commented) the *two* methods: `DistributeFish` & `DistributeSharks` (hopefully which could share some common base helper method, since they're so similar).

There also seems to be something very similar in `fishNearBy`, which has four *near* identical for-loops.  The may be able to be abstracted out into a helper method that `fishNearBy` can call 4 times, thus saving on code and making **refactoring** of that logic easier in the future.

---

### Inheritance:  <strike>The Answer to All your Problems</strike>   (NOT)

As you mentioned in [your question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/c-wa-tor-simulation-making-my-code-more-object-oriented), "inheritance for fish and shark from the cell class", **might** be a good idea.  It depends if your behaviours can be made generic enough to apply to both.

For example, in the [Wikipedia page about Wa-tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa-Tor)^, it is stated:

> Since hunting for fish takes priority over mere movement, the rules for a shark are more complicated: from the adjacent points occupied by fish, select one at random, move there and devour the fish. If no fish are in the neighborhood, **the shark moves just as a fish does**, avoiding its fellow sharks.
>
> *(Emphasis added)*

<sup>^ Wikipedia attributes this (in a quotation) to *Dewdney (1984) "Sharks and fish Wage an ecological War on the toroidal planet Wa-Tor", Scientific American December pg I4—22*</sup>

From reading this, I would have (as an OOP programmer naturally would,) thought that the `move` behaviour of a *fish* would therefore be something **re-usable** for a shark.

However, in your code it seems fish `move` while sharks `hunt`, and no re-use of `move` is made at all.  This is something you may want to consider refactoring if you were to make `Shark` and `Fish` classes.  For example, the current `hunt` method would become an overloaded `move` method on `Shark`.  `Shark` would inherit from `Fish` (since a shark is a type of fish), and `Fish` would contain (a modified version of) the current `move` method.  This way that code has been made **re-usble** (one of the goals of an OOP programmer).

---

### Some General Code Smells

In addition to these, there are also just some general things I noticed going through you code, which as you say "is a mess" (well, a small mess anyway).

1. Multiple Random generators and instance member hiding.  You class has `Random rnd = new Random();`, which is then repeated inside of `hunt` (not in itself a big issue, although I don't know why you need a different generator).  But inside `hunt`, it is *also* named `rnd`, which means (as Visual Studio would underline it and say) that it ***hides* the instance member `rnd`* (in the class).
2. `move` takes a `fishTypeEnum` argument (named `type`, probably should be fishType to avoid confusion), and then uses this **JUST** to check that it is a *fish*.  However, the *ONLY* place that `move` is called (in `tick`), this check is already done *before* `move` is called!  The value `fishTypeEnum.fish` is also **hard-coded** into the call, making the if-statement to check the value inside `move` completely redundant.
3. This last one isn't really a 'coding' issue, but I'll include it for completeness.  In your code, your comment for `tick` states that it represents a "round", however the [Wikipedia page about Wa-tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa-Tor) says that these should be called "chronons".

---

Overall, I think your code is suffering from a lack of clarity of thought when designing.  It has a "code first" feel, and as such the data structures and modelling are lacking.  Some parts of it feel very procedural in style, other parts just seem more like spaghetti code (lacking a defined style).

I hope I've helped you with the things I've highlighted, comment if there's anything I've said that needs more explanation, or if you'd like me to go into more detail on anything.

Comment: just wow! I'll start redesigning the code asap

Comment: i hope a follow-up question is not against the rules:

i seperated the presentation from the logic by creating a new Class Simulation, which contains all the world-parameters.
1. A simulation object is created from the WaTor (renamed Form1) Class. 
2. From the simulation object, cell Objects are created.
How can the cell objects access variables from the simulation instance that was created from the WaTor Class? My first thought would be to use a pointer to the object, but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Technically yes, but technically you're allowed to edit the question.. So technically, I don't think anybody minds? ;P
As you say, **from the `Simulation` object**, `Cell` objects (technically called "_instances_," but let's not get too technical) are [created](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_lifetime#Object_creation). That part sounds good so far.  My spidey-senses detect a C-programmer.. The `Cell` doesn't need to "access variables from `Simulation`" - these can be _passed_ to the `Cell(foo,bar)` [constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29).